# BigQuery UDF Array<TIMESTAMP> return. Failed to coerce output value to type TIMESTAMP

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using a BigQuery JavaScript UDF to return an array of dates. The array must a timestamp array, similar to the  GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY() function in order to match an UNNEST CASE WHEN.

The problem occurs when I return the timestamp array from my JavaScript UDF. The array returns fine if I specify RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>, but when I use RETURNS ARRAY<TIMESTAMP> BigQuery seems to not be able to coerce the string format of the dates.

I have tried numerous string formats, i.e. 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss', 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00+00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS UTC'.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  getCalendarDateArray(date_start STRING,
    date_end STRING,
    frequency STRING,
    unit STRING,
    value INT64,
    parent STRING,
    next_date TIMESTAMP)

  RETURNS ARRAY<TIMESTAMP>

  LANGUAGE js AS

"""

    let dates_array = getTimestampArray(date_start, date_end, frequency, unit, value, parent, next_date);
    return dates_array;


"""
OPTIONS
  ( library=["gs://my-bucket/myfunction.js"] );
```

UDF output is currently an array of formatted date strings which cannot be coerced to timestamp. What is the proper string format in order for BigQuery to coerce to timestamp successfully?

```
[
      "2019-07-02",
      "2019-07-09",
      "2019-07-16",
      "2019-07-23",
      "2019-07-30"
    ]
```

Comment: what is the reason in using expensive JS UDF instead of using built-in `GENERATE_..._ARRAY()` family of functions?

Comment: I am generating recurring dates based on calendar dates, not just set intervals. For instance: every 2nd day of week starting from X date, or every 3rd Week of month. However, after experimenting with UDF it is clear that it is expensive and time consuming. Instead I am going to simply calculate the dates for each row before uploading to bigquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Date()`:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  getCalendarDateArray()
  RETURNS ARRAY<TIMESTAMP>
  LANGUAGE js AS
"""
  return [Date('2018-03-03 10:10:10')]
""";

SELECT getCalendarDateArray() dates
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't try this. Using moment.js and thought string return was needed. Thanks Felipe. Hope you are doing well, we met a long time ago.

Comment: It took me a while to figure this out. I passed a `TIMESTAMP` into the UDF and then used object introspection to figure out its type. Thanks for asking the question! At least we have the solution to this error documented now :). Please accept the answer if it's the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend the accepted answer by Felipe Hoffa, the following example probably shows what happens:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION getDate_fail() RETURNS TIMESTAMP 
LANGUAGE js AS """ return Date.now()""";

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION getDate_succeed() RETURNS TIMESTAMP 
LANGUAGE js AS """ return Date(Date.now())""";
```

The former function throws a coercion exception, while the latter succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying this with non-TEMP UDF functions but I get the compilation timestamp constantly. Is this the intended behavior?

P.S. No JavaScript expert :)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `my_dataset.my_ts`() RETURNS TIMESTAMP LANGUAGE js AS """return Date(Date.now())""";