# BigQuery : Returning timestamp from JS udf throwing "Failed to coerce output value to type TIMESTAMP"

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have a bigquery code.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION to_struct_attributes(input STRING)
RETURNS STRUCT<status_code STRING, created_time TIMESTAMP>
LANGUAGE js AS """
    let res = JSON.parse(input);
    res['created_time'] = Date(res['created_time'])
    return res;
""";

SELECT 
5 AS ID,
to_struct_attributes(
    TO_JSON_STRING(
        STRUCT(
           TIMESTAMP(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', '20220215175959','America/Los_Angeles')) AS created_time 
        )
    )
) AS ATTRIBUTES;
```

When I execute this, I'm getting the following error:

```
Failed to coerce output value "2022-02-16 01:59:59+00" to type TIMESTAMP
```

I feel this is quite strange, since BigQuery should be able to interpret it correctly and I haven't had this issue with any other datatypes. Also, if I do:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP("2022-02-16 01:59:59+00")
```

It returns:

```
2022-02-16 01:59:59 UTC
```

So BigQuery can indeed parse it correctly. I'm not sure why it doesn't happen for the UDF. On searching the internet, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56463112/13353898) and as the answer suggests, if I change the return statement to:

```
return Date(res.created_time);
```

It resolves the issue. But for a project of mine, doing it for every timestamp is not feasible due to the high number of struct columns.

So, I wanted to know if someone has a better alternative to it?

PS : I have removed a lot of non-essential parts from the above example, so this might look a bit abstract. Also, the actual use-case is a bit different and complex that's why I need that JS udf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do what you want is to implement the following code.

```
return Date(res.created_time);
```

This happens when you pass a `TIMESTAMP` to a `UDF`, it is represented as a `DATE` object, as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions). This is like a return of a `TIMESTAMP` from a [JavaScript UDF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), where you need to construct and return a `DATE` object.

Comment: I agree that when we pass TIMESTAMP to UDF, it gets sent as Javascript Date. But I wanted to understand why the format is not being parsed by BigQuery on return considering that it's a valid timestamp value.

Comment: @Anshul It is not being parsed by BigQuery because `TIMESTAMP` on BigQuery data type has a direct mapping to `DATE` of JavaScript data type. Even if it is a valid `TIMESTAMP` value that you are passing on `UDF`, it converts it to a `DATE` object. “[Some SQL types have a direct mapping to JavaScript types, but others do not.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#:~:text=TIMESTAMP,of%20the%20timestamp)”.

Comment: @Anshul Did you have time to check it out?

Comment: Hi @Jose Gutierrez Paliza, sorry for the late reply. I was away due to personal work. I think you are right and don't think my use case can be automatically parsed by BigQuery.